# What's the name of this Godzilla movie?

Tags: story-identification, godzilla

During the 70s I saw what must have been a Japanese Godzilla movie. In fact it had three different Godzillas: a rocky one, a robot one, and a normal Godzilla.

Does anyone know the name of this movie?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Was it actually Japanese or just Japanese-style? What language did you see it in? Can you remember any other details?

Comment: @MissMonicaE: I watched it over thirty years ago; so the details are pretty hazy! I'm assuming it was Japanese, because I recall that one of the actresses looked Japanese; and of course Godzilla is associated with Japanese B-movies; I think it had English sub-titles which would point it to being a foreign movie; to be honest, at that age I was just interested in the big, giant dinosaurs...if I recall any more details I'll put them in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the movie you are thinking of is [Godzilla vs Space Godzilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._SpaceGodzilla) . The "rocky" Godzilla would be Space Godzilla, and the robotic "Godzilla" you recall is actually M.O.G.U.E.R.A, a mecha rebuilt from remains of Mechagodzilla.

[image: Poster for the movie]

Comment: Actually the reference to space makes sense, because the robot Godzilla could fly! I'll have to check out the movie and see if this is the one. Thanks for pointing it out.